# datepicker not visible with the date in edit form

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to do a editForm , which is getting all the values correctly from the database. The problem is that either the date is visible or just datepicker.  The 'View Page Source is showing the correct value'
[image]
This is how I am displaying the property in Model

```
   [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

I have tried both the input tag and the @Html tag and both give different results
With just the input tag it just shows the datepicker with dd/mm/yyyy

```
                    <div class="form row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label asp-for="DateOfBirth" class="col-auto col-form-label small form-text">Date Of Birth</label>
                            <div class="col">
                                <input asp-for="DateOfBirth" class="form-control ui-datepicker" type="date" placeholder="Date of Birth" value="@Model.DateOfBirth.ToShortDateString()" asp-format="dd/mm/yyyy" />
```

and with the @Html it just shows the correct date but not datepicker

```
  @*@{
                                    string parameterValue = @Model.DateOfBirth.ToShortDateString();
                                }
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => parameterValue, new { @class = "form-control ui-datepicker" })*@
                                <span asp-validation-for="DateOfBirth"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

How can I get both the date and datepicker displayed in the edit form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> just the input tag it just shows the datepicker with dd/mm/yyyy

1. This is because you **specified** the **type** of **input** as **date**.

   - type="**date**"
2. About `<input type="date">`,you need to know:

   1. The **displayed date format** will **differ from the actual value** — the displayed date is formatted **based on the locale of the user's browser**, but the **parsed value** is **always** **formatted yyyy-mm-dd**.
   2. Therefore, when your **input value** is **not in yyyy-mm-dd format**, it will **not be displayed** **correctly**.
   3. **[input elements of type="date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)"**

> How can I get both the date and datepicker displayed in the edit form?

1. I suggest you combine **jquery Datepicker** to achieve your needs.
2. I wrote an example, you can refer to it.

   1. You need to reference the **jquery-ui.css** and **jquery-ui.js** files.

      - You can **install** **jqueryui** by **right-clicking** **wwwroot** and selecting **Add->Client-Side Library**.
      - [image]
   2. **Model**

      - ```
        public class TestDate
        {
           [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
           public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        }
        ```
   3. **Controller**

      - ```
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
          TestDate model = new TestDate {  DateOfBirth=DateTime.Now};
          return View(model);
        }
        ```
   4. **View**

      - ```
        @model WebApplication24.Models.TestDate
        <link href="~/jqueryui/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <input asp-for="DateOfBirth" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Date of Birth" />
        @section scripts{
            <script src="~/jqueryui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <script>
                $(function () {
                    $("#DateOfBirth").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
                });
            </script>
        }
        ```
   5. **Result**

      - [image]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!!

Answer (score 0):

Changed the input to this and it solved the issue

`<input asp-for="DateOfBirth" class="form-control ui-datepicker" type="date"
placeholder="Date of Birth" value="@Model.DateOfBirth.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" />